# ASP.Net Controller Action return only after task completion

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, task-parallel-library

```
 public ActionResult Favorites()
    {
        var favs = new List<Article>();
        var tFavs = new Task(() =>
        {
            favs = _favorites.GetFavorites(_currentUserId).ToList();
        });
        tFavs.Start();
        if (tFavs.IsCompleted)
        {
            ViewBag.Content = favs;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

In the code above, how can I ensure that return View is only called after the task is complete? Currently it throws an error on the view because ViewBag.Content is null.

Comment: If you use async methods, you can call await on return view. Take a look at: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this using `Task` and `await`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Favorites()
{

  ViewBag.Content = await _favorites.GetGetFavoritesAsync(_currentUserId).ToListAsync();
  return View();
}
```

and `GetFavoritesAsync()` will look like this:

```
public async Task<List<Article>> GetFavoritesAsync(int currentUserId)
{
   var query = from a in db.Articles
               where a.UserId = currentUserId
               select a;

   List<Article> articles = await query.ToListAsync();
   return articles;
}
```

For more detailed understanding about creating async actions read [**Creating Asynchronous Actions in ASP.NET MVC**](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/creating-asynchronous-actions-in-asp.net-mvc.htm)

Comment: What namespaces need to be used to use `async Task<>`

Comment: What if I have multiple tasks in the same action running in parallel and if I have to wait for them to be completed before returning the view?

Comment: @xoail I undeleted my original answer and updated it as based on your above comment i believe that is what you want to achieve, let me know whether it suits your needs, or I'll delete again.

Answer (score 0):

Asker in one of the comments posted the following:

> What if I have multiple tasks in the same action running in parallel and **if I have to wait for them to be completed before returning the view**?

Therefore I updated my original answer and undeleted it, see below code, because I believe this approach is OK in the given situation.

```
public ActionResult Favorites()
{
    // Create and start all tasks first.
    var tFavs = new Task<List<Article>>(() =>
        _favorites.GetFavorites(_currentUserId).ToList());
    tFavs.Start();
    var task2 = new Task<SomeType>(() => new SomeType());
    task2.Start();

    // Wait for the results.
    ViewBag.Content = tFavs.Result;
    ViewBag.Content2 = task2.Result;
    return View();
}
```

If tasks have dependencies between themselves then you can easily create a deadlock because of using [`Result`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx) so watch out for that.

But of course, you may want to have asynchronous actions when you expect long running web service calls. Then answer provided by Ehsan Sajjad is the correct one.

Comment: There's no point in offloading work to another thread if you're just going to synchronously wait for the result.  You might as well just do the work in the original thread.

Comment: Not saying the opposite, but thats not how the question stands I believe.

Comment: So you're knowingly providing a solution that isn't going to work, without so much as a single word of explanation, but because the question itself is asking for what he actually needs to have you don't care?

Comment: @Servy Sorry but what do you mean by "not going to work"? Is it not going to write expected value into `ViewBag.Content`? Also, what if asker wants to execute some work after calling `tFavs.Start();` and the `tFavs.Result` will only be called afterwards? As for a word of explanation - askers are free to ask for more details in comments if, after running the code, the provided solution is not clear to them.